# Gycwin: c compiler cannot create executables - tidalcycles installation

Tags: c, windows, haskell, gcc

I'm trying to install tidalcycles (http://tidalcycles.org/getting_started.html), but i had problems running the  `cabal install tidal` command.
Originally i had an issue due to windows10 compatibility, so I installed Cygwin and i tried to run the command from his shell. But then this occurs:

```
Andrea@Pc_di_Andrea ~
$ cabal install tidal
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring old-time-1.1.0.3...
Configuring network-2.6.2.1...
Failed to install old-time-1.1.0.3
Build log ( C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\old-time-1.1.0.3.log):
Configuring old-time-1.1.0.3...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler
checking for gcc... C:\PROGRA~1\HASKEL~1\802E01~1.1\mingw\bin\gcc.exe
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/cabal-tmp-8957/old-time-1.1.0.3':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
cabal: Leaving directory 'C:\cygwin\tmp\cabal-tmp-8957\old-time-1.1.0.3'
Failed to install network-2.6.2.1
Build log ( C:\Users\Andrea\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\network-2.6.2.1.log ):
Configuring network-2.6.2.1...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler
checking build system type... i686-pc-cygwin
checking host system type... i686-pc-cygwin
checking for gcc... C:\PROGRA~1\HASKEL~1\802E01~1.1\mingw\bin\gcc.exe
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/cabal-tmp-8956/network-2.6.2.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
cabal: Leaving directory 'C:\cygwin\tmp\cabal-tmp-8956\network-2.6.2.1'
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
hosc-0.15 depends on network-2.6.2.1 which failed to install.
mersenne-random-pure64-0.2.0.5 depends on old-time-1.1.0.3 which failed to
install.
network-2.6.2.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 77
old-time-1.1.0.3 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 77
tidal-0.8 depends on old-time-1.1.0.3 which failed to install.
websockets-0.9.6.2 depends on network-2.6.2.1 which failed to install.
```

So, it says that the

```
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

is the problem. I'm running the 32bit version, and the c compiler should be installed, since i get this reply from the system:

```
Andrea@Pc_di_Andrea ~
$  echo; gcc --version; echo; g++ --version;

gcc (GCC) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


g++ (GCC) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I'm a total newbie to this 'cygwin enviroment' and  I apologize if my question is not appropriate, but I read some guides about this c compiler problem and i didn't understand what i'm doing wrong, at all.

Comment: Cyg**win** is not and not related to Linux

Comment: Pardon me. I'll edit it.

Comment: The configure script will have created a log file, as indeed it tells you.  That log file should show you details of the test that configure performed that led it to conclude that your compiler does not work -- the code it tried to compile, the compilation command, and how it attempted to run the compiled result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem: I didn't complete Haskell installation editing the cabal `config.file`, with

```
extra-prog-path: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.1\msys\usr\bin
extra-lib-dirs: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.1\mingw\lib
extra-include-dirs: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.1\mingw\include+
```

as this source https://www.haskell.org/platform/ says.

Comment: you will have problems with the path to the `bin`, `lib`, and `include` directories containing spaces.  Suggest moving the tool chain.  HOWEVER, the `mingw` is for development under `windows` not under `cygwin`.  BUT if your using `cygwin`, 1) must have installed the `cygwin` specific tool chain 2) must have run the `startup batch` file for `cygwin` before doing anything else.   Per your question, those steps have not been properly performed.

Comment: in the end, i ran the `cabal install tidal` from the windows cmd prompt, so i had no problems. surely it used cygwin as the tool chain